# FrontBoardServices framework crashes at iOS app launch

Tags: ios, swift, exception, crash

I have multiple end users experiencing the same crash with my last version uploaded to the appstore.

Here is the crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006e2558 __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022152b118 pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1670)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001c8c9f178 abort + 180 (abort.c:118)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000221469bf8 abort_message + 132 (:-1)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000221459428 demangling_terminate_handler() + 320
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ba825eb4 _objc_terminate() + 160 (objc-exception.mm:501)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000221468fbc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (:-1)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000221468f60 std::terminate() + 56 (:-1)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c8c3eec0 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:563)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001c8c4291c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264 (queue.c:496)
10  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001d77f7188 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52 (FBSSerialQueue.m:157)
11  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001d77f6d24 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 220 (FBSSerialQueue.m:181)
12  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001d77f95d0 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28 (FBSSerialQueue.m:194)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c1842128 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1957)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c184e7b4 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176 (CFRunLoop.c:2001)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c17d3648 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 340 (CFRunLoop.c:2046)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c17e90d4 __CFRunLoopRun + 828 (CFRunLoop.c:2953)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c17ee3ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
18  GraphicsServices                0x00000001fccb335c GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c3b7b6e8 -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3782)
20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c3b7b34c UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5372)
21  LibertyMutual                   0x0000000100ba39e4 main + 176 (main.swift:11)
22  dyld                            0x00000001e0ceedec start + 2220 (dyldMain.cpp:1165)

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006dbc84 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006eeb54 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006eee2c mach_msg_overwrite + 540 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006dc1c8 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c17e8024 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2622)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c17e9250 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3005)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c17ee3ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
7   Foundation                      0x00000001bba76fd4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001bba76ebc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 64 (NSRunLoop.m:420)
9   UIKitCore                       0x00000001c3cae3fc -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 416 (UIEventFetcher.m:1376)
10  Foundation                      0x00000001bba90544 __NSThread__start__ + 716 (NSThread.m:963)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002215256b8 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b88 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006dbc84 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006eeb54 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006eee2c mach_msg_overwrite + 540 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006dc1c8 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c17e8024 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2622)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c17e9250 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3005)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c17ee3ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c1830ea4 CFRunLoopRun + 64 (CFRunLoop.c:3444)
8   CoreMotion                      0x00000001ccd72248 CLMotionCore::runMotionThread(void*) + 1208 (CLMotionCore.mm:376)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002215256b8 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b88 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006dc558 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022152c0a4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1276 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   Foundation                      0x00000001bba51e88 -[NSCondition waitUntilDate:] + 132 (NSLock.m:81)
3   CMTMobileLibrary                0x0000000103e19f68 -[CMTTripUploader waitOnCondition:] + 184 (CMTTripUploader.m:334)
4   CMTMobileLibrary                0x0000000103e18c44 -[CMTTripUploader runSendingThread] + 380 (CMTTripUploader.m:129)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001bba90544 __NSThread__start__ + 716 (NSThread.m:963)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002215256b8 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b88 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006dc558 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022152c0a4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1276 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   Foundation                      0x00000001bba51e88 -[NSCondition waitUntilDate:] + 132 (NSLock.m:81)
3   CMTMobileLibrary                0x0000000103d7ca5c -[CMTPeriodicDataReceiver waitOnCondition:] + 184 (CMTPeriodicDataReceiver.m:156)
4   CMTMobileLibrary                0x0000000103d7c42c -[CMTPeriodicDataReceiver runFetchThread] + 120 (CMTPeriodicDataReceiver.m:91)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001bba90544 __NSThread__start__ + 716 (NSThread.m:963)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002215256b8 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b88 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006dbc84 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006eeb54 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006eee2c mach_msg_overwrite + 540 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006dc1c8 mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c17e8024 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2622)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c17e9250 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208 (CFRunLoop.c:3005)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c17ee3ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
7   CFNetwork                       0x00000001c29d9580 +[__CFN_CoreSchedulingSetRunnable _run:] + 392 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1562)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001bba90544 __NSThread__start__ + 716 (NSThread.m:963)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002215256b8 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b88 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006dc558 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022152c0a4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1276 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   Foundation                      0x00000001bba51e88 -[NSCondition waitUntilDate:] + 132 (NSLock.m:81)
3   CMTMobileLibrary                0x0000000103d7ca5c -[CMTPeriodicDataReceiver waitOnCondition:] + 184 (CMTPeriodicDataReceiver.m:156)
4   CMTMobileLibrary                0x0000000103d7c42c -[CMTPeriodicDataReceiver runFetchThread] + 120 (CMTPeriodicDataReceiver.m:91)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001bba90544 __NSThread__start__ + 716 (NSThread.m:963)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002215256b8 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b88 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006dc558 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022152c0a4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1276 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   Foundation                      0x00000001bba51e88 -[NSCondition waitUntilDate:] + 132 (NSLock.m:81)
3   CMTMobileLibrary                0x0000000103def888 -[CMTPersistentLog runSendingThread] + 1620 (CMTPersistentLog.m:992)
4   Foundation                      0x00000001bba90544 __NSThread__start__ + 716 (NSThread.m:963)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002215256b8 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b88 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006dc558 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022152c0a4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1276 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   Foundation                      0x00000001bba51e88 -[NSCondition waitUntilDate:] + 132 (NSLock.m:81)
3   CMTMobileLibrary                0x0000000103dcf5fc -[CMTPersistingNetworkQueue sendingLoop] + 1376 (CMTPersistingNetworkQueue.m:214)
4   Foundation                      0x00000001bba90544 __NSThread__start__ + 716 (NSThread.m:963)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002215256b8 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b88 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b74 _pthread_cond_updateval + 256 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b74 _pthread_cond_updateval + 256 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b74 _pthread_cond_updateval + 256 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006dc558 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022152c0a4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1276 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   Foundation                      0x00000001bba51e88 -[NSCondition waitUntilDate:] + 132 (NSLock.m:81)
3   CMTMobileLibrary                0x0000000103e19f68 -[CMTTripUploader waitOnCondition:] + 184 (CMTTripUploader.m:334)
4   CMTMobileLibrary                0x0000000103e18c44 -[CMTTripUploader runSendingThread] + 380 (CMTTripUploader.m:129)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001bba90544 __NSThread__start__ + 716 (NSThread.m:963)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002215256b8 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b88 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000002006dc558 __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022152c0a4 _pthread_cond_wait + 1276 (pthread_cond.c:862)
2   Foundation                      0x00000001bba51e88 -[NSCondition waitUntilDate:] + 132 (NSLock.m:81)
3   CMTMobileLibrary                0x0000000103d7ca5c -[CMTPeriodicDataReceiver waitOnCondition:] + 184 (CMTPeriodicDataReceiver.m:156)
4   CMTMobileLibrary                0x0000000103d7c42c -[CMTPeriodicDataReceiver runFetchThread] + 120 (CMTPeriodicDataReceiver.m:91)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001bba90544 __NSThread__start__ + 716 (NSThread.m:963)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002215256b8 _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b88 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b74 _pthread_cond_updateval + 256 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b74 _pthread_cond_updateval + 256 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b74 _pthread_cond_updateval + 256 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b74 _pthread_cond_updateval + 256 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b74 _pthread_cond_updateval + 256 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000221524b74 _pthread_cond_updateval + 256 (pthread_cond.c:992)


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x000000022146d618   x5: 0x000000016f2625d0   x6: 0x0000000000000074   x7: 0x000000016f261238
    x8: 0xad90955a0a6c0b4f   x9: 0xad90955812650ecf  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x0000000000000025
   x12: 0x0000000000000025  x13: 0x00000000001ff800  x14: 0x00000000000007fb  x15: 0x00000000fd410838
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000218090580  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000103  x21: 0x0000000218090660  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000218090660
   x24: 0x00000002830d0310  x25: 0x0000000000000002  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x00000000211200d5
   x28: 0x0000000000000001   fp: 0x000000016f262540   lr: 0x000000022152b118
    sp: 0x000000016f262520   pc: 0x00000002006e2558 cpsr: 0x40001000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

I was trying to understand the logs and it seems the user is launching the app on Thread 0 frames 22 to 19 and then on frames 12, 11, and 10 some methods from `FrontBoardServices` framework are being called. After that, C++ library calls a terminate method and on frame 5 I see an `objc-exception` and right after that, the app is killed by the OS.

This crash only happens with end users. Our QA team and development team are not able to replicate it.

Is this `FrontBoardServices` a private framework? I didn't find any information about it. I don't understand in which circumstances this framework is being used.

Any information you can give will be very welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Front board services is the "launcher". It is the service that reacts to a user tapping on your app icon and launches/opens your app. It also handles app terminations It looks like `fatalError` or similar was called or maybe something failed to load/launch. Do you have a 3rd party crash reporter integrated that might give you more information?

Comment: Hey @Paulw11 thanks for your reply. I have one called AppDynamics, but is not able to symbolicate the entire crash. I was able to symbolicate this one manually from Xcode.